# How can I include a hyperlink to a cell in another sheet?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I would like to make the text displayed to become a hyperlink that will take you to the sheet and cell when the text displayed is selected.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thank you in advance,

```
If wb.sheets("Coversheet").Cells(lastRowC, 8) <> WS.Cells(i, 5) Then
    wb.sheets("Coversheet").Cells(lastRowC + 1, 2) = "Carrier"
    wb.sheets("Coversheet").Cells(lastRowC + 1, 3) = "Employee with a $0 salary found. Unable to calculate salary based benefits. Please rerun Census report"
    wb.sheets("Coversheet").Cells(lastRowC + 1, 4) = WS.Cells(i, 4).Hyperlinks(1).Address
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do that in your case to create the hyperlink. It's flexible and easy to manipulate.

```
Dim hyperlinkLocation As String
hyperlinkLocation = "[ActiveWorkBook.Name"&".xls]1!A1" '<- 1 is the sheet index (important in your case)   


 ActiveWorkSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.(where the link is), Address:=hyperlinkLockation, _ 
        TextToDisplay:=(name of the link)
```